# Вопрос по решению задачи про улитку на python

Tags: python

Нужно решить задачку на пайтон. Решить нужно используя ***только арифметику***.
Улитка ползет по вертикальному шесту высотой H метров, поднимаясь за день на A метров, а за ночь спускаясь на B метров. На какой день улитка доползет до вершины шеста?
Программа получает на вход целые H, A, B. Гарантируется, что A > B ≥ 0.
Программа должна вывести одно натуральное число.
Придумал такое решение, но почему то не пропускает

```
H = int(input())
A = int(input())
B = int(input())
print(1 + (H - A) // (A - B))
```

Comment: *но почему то не пропускает* да потому что по твоему решению в последние дни несчастная улитка вынуждена будет парить над верхушкой шеста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот одно из решений.

```
H = int(input("Высота столба : "))
A = int(input("Пробег вверх за день : "))
B = int(input("Пробег вниз за ночь : "))

h_remain = H - A # остаток высоты столба после подъёма за день
d_day = A - B    # расстояние, на которое поднимется улитка за сутки 
# классическая формула
days = (h_remain - 1) // d_day + 1 + 1  # второе +1 здесь эмулирует округление вверх
# или более сложная
# days = 1 + (h_remain // d_day) + (h_remain % d_day + d_day - 1) // d_day

print(days)
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте это решение:

```
import math

h = int(input())
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
print(math.ceil((h - a) / (a - b)) + 1)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
h = int(input())
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
print((h - a) // (a - b) + 1 + 0**0**((h - a) % (a - b))) #при наличии остатка, просто добавляем ещё один день
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
h = int(input())
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
print(math.ceil((h-b)/(a-b)))
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]